# How to get richtext box value in other form?

Tags: c#-3.0

I am creating a simple C# windows application and I want to access my richtextbox value in other from. I am able to access the richtextbox but when i am trying to access the value of that it gives me null.

Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: Can you post the code that fetches the value?

Answer (score 0):

if you use winforms richtextbox then you can simple do the following action

```
richtextbox2.Text = richtextbox1.Text;
```

if you use wpf richtextbox the look at the msdn examples for loading and saving TextRanges from/to streams.

save: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598701.aspx

load: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.load.aspx

here are the code examples from msdn

```
// This method accepts an input stream and a corresponding data format.  The method
// will attempt to load the input stream into a TextRange selection, apply Bold formatting
// to the selection, save the reformatted selection to an alternat stream, and return 
// the reformatted stream.  
Stream BoldFormatStream(Stream inputStream, string dataFormat)
{
    // A text container to read the stream into.
    FlowDocument workDoc = new FlowDocument();
    TextRange selection = new TextRange(workDoc.ContentStart, workDoc.ContentEnd);
    Stream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    try
    {
        // Check for a valid data format, and then attempt to load the input stream
        // into the current selection.  Note that CanLoad ONLY checks whether dataFormat
        // is a currently supported data format for loading a TextRange.  It does not 
        // verify that the stream actually contains the specified format.  An exception 
        // may be raised when there is a mismatch between the specified data format and 
        // the data in the stream. 
        if (selection.CanLoad(dataFormat))
            selection.Load(inputStream, dataFormat);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { return outputStream; /* Load failure; return a null stream. */ }

    // Apply Bold formatting to the selection, if it is not empty.
    if (!selection.IsEmpty)
        selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);

    // Save the formatted selection to a stream, and return the stream.
    if (selection.CanSave(dataFormat))
        selection.Save(outputStream, dataFormat);

    return outputStream;
}
```